# Celery: Display log messages from task on webserver?

Tags: python, celery

In my celery task, I am using the following logging:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@celery.task(bind=True)
def deploy_heroku_app(self, cloaker_id):
  logger.debug('Hello')
```

Right now I can see the logs being outputted on the window that is running my celery worker.

I would like to display these logs to a page on my webserver so my users can see the live progress of their task.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible? Sure. A few different ways you could do that. One way could be to output to a file that is in the webservers web directory, or otherwise have a web application read, parse, and display the log.

Comment: @sytech I just realized that celery and my webserver are **separate** processes. So this means I pretty much can't rely on my logger to work right?

Comment: How do you figure that? Are they on the same host? Suppose your logger outputs to a file `/var/logs/celery/foo_app.log` -- As long as your webserver can read that file, it should be possible, even if they are separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Celery backend to get status of your task. So when you start a new async task you get task ID. You can use it to query table in backend to get status and other information about your task. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results

Also you can use different backends for celery: mysql, postgres etc